# Why can't I add a main to my library in golang?

Tags: go, package, program-entry-point, code-organization

I'm having trouble achieving what should be an easy task. I understand the GitHub model for code organization (ie a library repo and an app repo that consumes the library). I think it's fantastic. But I find often that I want `mylib` to come bundled with a simple executable in a single `main.go` file. The `main.go` should be `package main` and should import `mylib`. In other words, it should be an exact documentation of how to build an app that consumes this library.

My point is, since it is often enough convenient to provide a simple command line interface that wraps your library, there should be an easy way to do this without having to make another repo, and golang should help.

I'd like something like the following:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/me/mylib
    mylib.go
    mylib_also.go
    main.go
```

where `mylib` is the library (`package mylib`) and `main.go` is `package main` and on running `go install` it generates `bin/mylib` and `pkg/mylib.a`.

Either `main.go` should import `"github.com/me/mylib"` (if I do that now, I get cyclical import error) or `go` would understand what's happening since this feature should be built in and the one `main.go` in the repo generates the exec. Probably requiring the import (and dropping the cyclical error) is the better way.

Right now, I have to do

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/me/mylib
    mylib/
        mylib.go
    main.go
```

So I have to import github.com/me/mylib/mylib which is ridiculous.

In sum, `go install` should allow the special case of a package and a main which imports the package and provides a simple cli that demonstrates the packages API. The GitHub model promotes two repos, but it should be easy to do simple clis in one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't have multiple packages per folder. Go operates on a package-level, not a file level.

Convention in this case—a binary that consumes your library—is to create a `cmd` folder with your package main - i.e. as per https://github.com/bradfitz/camlistore/tree/master/cmd or https://github.com/boltdb/bolt

In your case this would be:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/me/mylib
    mylib/
      mylib.go
      README.md
      cmd/
        your-lib-tool/
          main.go
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I wanted. I had tried before with `main` instead of `cmd` but with `main/main.go` or `main/mylib.go` I was getting binaries called `main`. I guess it needs two levels down?

Comment: `package main` takes the name of the folder it resides in (by default) - you can just have one level if you want and call it `yourlib-cli`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a convenient, little wrapper, just some command line interface to your lib for demonstration purpose and it is okay if the main program is not built on `go get` (and not during simple `go build` and `go install`) but you are okay by running it via `go run main.go` or building it manually e.g. with `6g`: Just use a build tag (see http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) in main.go:

```
// +build ignore
```

and you won't need a different folder or repo.

Comment: will this give me a $GOPATH/bin/mylib ? I'd prefer to be able to get it all with a single go install

Comment: Exactly. I want to install the executable. The solution above nails it.