# Import a github managed go package

Tags: go, go-modules

I am new to go module building. What im trying to do is to create a go library with commonly used methods that other developers can use in their go code.

So first in my internal github, Ive created a repo `https://internalgithub/<org>/lib-go.git`

The repo structure looks like

```
$  tree
.
├── README.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

And the `main.go` file has the following content

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {}

func someFunctinDevelopersNeed(cluster bool) kubernetes.Interface {
    if cluster == false {
        var kubeconfig *string
.
.
    return clientset
}
```

The code is available in the master branch of my org github.

The next task to to write code that invokes this library and in turn invokes the methid `someFunctinDevelopersNeed`

So in my app code, my main.go looks like

```
package main

import "internalgithub/<org>/lib-go"


func main() {
    clientset = someFunctinDevelopersNeed()
.
.
}
```

But when I try to do  `go get -t -v internalgithub/<org>/lib-go`, I get

```
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
```

Is there something I have missed ?

**EDIT:**

Based on suggestions, now I have done the following

```
$ tree
.
├── README.md
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── kubernetes
    └── kubernetes.go
```

And `kubernetes.go` starts with

```
package kubernetes

import (
    "flag"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func someFunctinDevelopersNeed(cluster bool) kubernetes.Interface {
    if cluster == false {
        var kubeconfig *string
.
.
    return clientset
}
```

Even with these changes, I run into the same error

Comment: You can't import a `main` package. Put the shared code in a different package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318589/why-cant-i-add-a-main-to-my-library-in-golang?rq=1 appears to be very similar to your issue but possibly not a true duplicate.

Comment: Just to make sure Adrian correct comment is not misinterpreted under the influence of the answers. A package main is perfectly fine in a module (even multiple package main are common) but it is _totally_ _impossible_ to import any package main. Code you intend to be reused _must_ be put in any other package.

Comment: @Adrian I have edited my question with your suggestion and implemented it too. Im running into the same issue

Comment: @JasonStanley please check your edit, as it seems to have been cut off, and does not include the full changes made nor the error you're getting with the changes.

Answer (score -3):

If you write your own library, do not add `main` package.

You can see some popular golang libraries, like [go-gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin)(uses `gin.go` ), [gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm) (uses `gorm.go`)

For your case, if you just want to create a collection for most commonly used functions, you can add a package `utils` and put your implementation into `utils.go` or other `xxx.go` files